# Show that $H \mathrel{\unlhd} SU(2)$ contains matrices with all possible traces between $2$ and $2\cos \varphi_0 $.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, trace, quaternions, unitary-matrices

Let $H \mathrel{\unlhd} SU(2)$ that contains an element $A$ such that $\text{tr}(A)=2\cos \varphi_0 \neq \pm2$.
Use i),ii) to show that $H \mathrel{\unlhd} SU(2)$ contains matrices with all possible traces between $2$ and $2\cos \varphi_0 $.

i) Any element $A\in SU(2)$ is conjugate to a diagonal matrix $U_{\varphi}=\begin{bmatrix}
 e^{i\varphi }& 0 \\
 0&  e^{-i\varphi }\\
\end{bmatrix}$. $A$ uniquely determines $\varphi \in [0,\pi]$, and $\varphi=\cos ^{-1}(\text{tr}(A/2))$.

ii) If $B = \begin{bmatrix}
 \alpha & -\beta \\
 \overline{\beta} &  \overline{\alpha}\\
\end{bmatrix}$, $\text{tr}(BU_{\varphi}B^{-1}U_{\varphi}^{-1})=2(\alpha \overline{\alpha} + \beta\overline{\beta} \cos 2\varphi)$.

I think I have to show that $U_{\varphi_0} \in H$ first. Then, it would be possible to say that $BU_{\varphi_0}B^{-1} \in H$ for any $B \in SU(2)$ so that $BU_{\varphi_0}B^{-1}U_{\varphi_0}^{-1} := C \in H$. And, as $B$ can be any matrix, we can let $||\alpha||^2 = t \in [0,1] $ vary, and I can get the desired result. But, how do I show that $U_{\varphi_0} \in H$?

Edit: I showed that $U_{\varphi_0} \in H$. And, got the desired result.

Now, I would like to show that $H = SU(2)$ with the result I got and i), ii). So, I'm trying to show that "If $B \in SU(2)$, then $B \in H$." But, I'm stuck. Can I get some help with this?

My Approach:

Let $B \in SU(2)$.

Then, $\exists U_{\theta}$ s.t $P^{-1}BP = U_{\theta}$ for some $P \in SU(2)$.

Let $G_{U_{\theta}} \leq SU(2)$ that is generated by $U_{\theta}$.

Then, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $(U_{\theta})^n = P^{-1}B^n P \in G_{U_{\theta}}$.

But, note that $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $\text{tr} ((U_{\theta})^n)=\text{tr} (B^n) = 2 \cos n\theta \in [2\cos 2\varphi_0,2]$

Then, by the previous result, $B^n \in H$.

How do I show that $B \in H$ from here?

Comment: While showing ii) requires some computation, it is immediate that $\operatorname{tr}(B)=\alpha+\overline\alpha$, so I don't get your final question.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Sorry for the unclear question. My point was how to show that for any $B \in H$, $2\cos \varphi_0 < \text{tr}(B)<2$.

Comment: John, that is NOT what your task is. The claim is that to each real number $x$ such that $2\cos\phi_0<x<2$ there *exists* a matrix $C\in H$ such that $tr\, C=x$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh you're right. Thanks for pointing out this!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen But, I still don't see how. Can I get some hints?

Comment: Did you verify the formula in (ii)? Remember that if $\alpha\overline{\alpha}=t\in[0,1]$ then $\beta\overline{\beta}=???$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Then, $\beta \overline{\beta} = 1-t$, which is also between $0,1$. So, I put $t, 1-t$ in formula in ii), and I got the inequality $t \leq \frac{1}{1+\cos 2\varphi_0} = \frac{1}{2 \cos ^2 \varphi_0}$. Unfortunately, I still don't see a clear relation with ii).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen And, from this inequality, $\left\| \alpha \right\|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\cos\varphi_0 }$. Is this what I need?

Comment: Forget $\alpha$ and $\beta$. The relation between $x$ and $t$ is what you need. Let $t$ vary, and see what values of $x$ are covered. I now see that this way you get all the traces between $2\cos(2\phi_0)$ and $2$ instead of the claimed interval. Sorry about missing that detail.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think I have to show that $U_{\varphi_0} \in H$ first. Then, it is possible to say that $BU_{\varphi_0} B^{-1} \in H$ for any $B \in SU(2)$ so that $BU_{\varphi_0} B^{-1} U_{\varphi_0}^{-1} := C \in H$. And, as $B$ is any matrix, we can let $t$ vary and get a result like you said. But, how do I show that $U_{\varphi_0} \in H$?